# Is it ok to deselect these file types in advanced indexing options

Tags: file-extension, control-panel, search-indexing

Every single file type is selected in my indexing options for my Windows 10 PC. Only some of them are selected to index file contents as well, but they're all indexed at the very least with file properties.

Most of the file types I don't recognize, don't use, and don't plan to search for. Are there any other possible downsides to deselecting these from being indexed other than not seeing them in search results?

I'm trying to optimize searching on my PC.

[image]

Comment: Unselecting those files only matter if not only the files exist but there are enough of them, and they take up enough space, to somehow slow down the indexing process. Meaning whatever work you put into this might not result in any performance at all or such a small performance bump it might be imperceptible if not irrelevant. Better to just leave this stuff alone.

Answer (score 0):

The settings are there so that if you use a file of this type or extension and it is also in your Index Locations, then it will be indexed.

If you have the file, this is what you want.

If you do not have files of these types, then they will not be indexed.

So I would not change the file type settings. Leave them as is.

Why? If no files, there is nothing to index and so no penalty then. If you do sometimes have files of this type, then you will want them indexed.

No problem with what you have.